# AJAX/JSON Referencing?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

So I got pretty far in my quest to fill in values and such using JavaScript, but I'm a bit stuck. I'm pretty sure I'm referencing everything right, but my html table isn't outputting anything.

Basically I'm just trying to insert values from an JSON that an API retrieves out and then insert those values into a table using the double for-loop (outer loop that cycles through to find the perf_data and the inner loop to cycle through to find the values for each instance) to go through the JSON file, and depending upon those values, say if the value is above 7, change the color.

Using this JSON file:

```
{
  "product" : [ {
    "name" : "TxP",
    "id" : "TxP",
    "measurement" : [ {
      "id" : "222222",
      "alias" : "Site Login",
      "perf_data" : [ {
        "name" : "last_five_minute",
        "value" : "4.908",
        "duration" : "300",
        "unit" : "seconds"
      }, {
        "name" : "last_fifteen_minute",
        "value" : "3.99",
        "duration" : "900",
        "unit" : "seconds"
      } ],
      "avail_data" : [ {
        "name" : "last_five_minute",
        "value" : "100",
        "duration" : "300",
        "unit" : "percent"
      }, {
        "name" : "last_fifteen_minute",
        "value" : "100",
        "duration" : "900",
        "unit" : "percent"
      }, {
...
```

The .js file:

```
var jsonData = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "---";

function changeColor(input, value){
if (value < 7) {
    $(input).removeClass();
    $(input).addClass('high');
    }
}

jsonData.onload = funtion() {
  if (jsonData.status === 200){
    responseObject = JSON.parse(jsonData,responseText);

    var newContent = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < responseObject.perf_data.length; i++) {
         if (measurement.id === '222222') {
            for (var x = 0; x < responseObject.value.length; x++) {
                 newContent += '<td id = "part">'+changeColor(responseObject.value[x])
                                +'</td>';
            }
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = newContent;
         }
    }

  }
};

jsonData.open("GET",url,true);
jsonData.send();
```

My question ultimately boils down to is if I'm using the double for-loop right to go through the JSON file? I feel like this is where the error might be, but it seems like I'm referencing the address of the JSON file right to a bunch of examples I've seen with simpler JSON referencing... Or could it be something else?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You're referencing the object all wrong. you skipped `responseObject.product`, which contains an array. you also never defined `measurement`.

Comment: Look at your JavaScript console. You should see a reference error there because you have a typo.

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks... Wow I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Try debugging this in devtools, stepping through line-by-line and examining variables.

Comment: @torazaburo I actually found out a couple of minutes ago about that. I wonder why the book doesn't even have this tool mentioned!

Comment: It's really indispensable. Otherwise, it's like programming in the dark. Definitely recommend taking a few hours off and going through the docs in some detail. If your book doesn't discuss that, might be time for a new book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a lot of properties in the way. This could work, but I don't know if it makes sense for the (unknown to us) problem you need to solve

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseObject.product[0].measurement.length; i++) {
     if (responseObject.product[0].measurement[i].id === '222222') {
        for (var x = 0; x < responseObject.product[0].measurement[i].perf_data.length; x++) {
             newContent += '<td id = "part">'+changeColor(responseObject.product[0].measurement[i].perf_data[x].value)
                            +'</td>';
        }
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = newContent;
     }
}
```

Comment: Here's something on that topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: Ohhh. I really didn't learn arrays right because my professor had made us use vectors and C++ for my first programming class... which quite frankly I forgot a lot about. When I saw the comment above me about telling me how JSON was just an array within an array, that's when things clicked and I wrote up something. I'll get right back to this after I host the JSON file so I don't get the cross-site error.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks, I didn't noticed the downvoter is already encouraged to give a reason. I'll not ask the same from now on :)

Comment: @jperelli Alright so I'm testing it out and I keep getting an `Unexpected SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`, but weirdly at the index file, and it keeps generating it... Do you think it might be that the newContent part that is being added is in the wrong format?

Comment: @jperelli Your code has helped a lot big thanks! I went back and did some more fixing around with my parse error to find that the `Unexpected SyntaxError: Unexpected token o` was simply because I forgot to add `.responseText` in `JSON.parse(jsonData.responseText)`.